# How can I edit my question that was closed as opinion based?

Tags: support, specific-question

I asked the question [What steps do I take if I am indefinitely site-banned on Wikipedia?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/162414/what-steps-do-i-take-if-i-am-indefinitely-site-banned-on-wikipedia) about a serious situation that I am in. My question is currently closed as opinion-based. However, I need to ask a question for help. So, how can  I edit my question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question doesn't look to be a good fit for this site because it's about a specific case related to the Wikipedia's editors competency rules rather than about **using** Wikipedia.

You might ask on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com) for a site recommendation for that kind of questions.

Comment: I doubt asking on MSE will be of much help, because the steps OP will need to take will necessarily depend on the circumstances/reasoning behind their ban; that's not something any Stack Exchange user will know. OP's better off just reviewing the relevant portions of [Wikipedia's banning policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Banning_policy).